# Undefined array key error with PHPunit test function using PDO SQL INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, phpunit

I'm using phpstorm.

I already have a working test in my test class, and I'm trying to get this new function test working. It tests a simple INSERT INTO SQL statement, and I have all the data to be used in an array, and I use PDO and have created a mock of all the details.

I have the actual function that is being tested actually working. So there aren't any problems with that.

I have included the code below:

```
public function testSetTimestampCount()
    {
        $mysqli = (new db_connection())->connection();

        $validData = [
            'id' => '99',
            'ip' => '127.0.0.1'
        ];



        $table = 'ip';

        $stmt = $this->createMock(\PDOStatement::class);
        $stmt->expects($this->once())
            ->method('execute')
            ->will(returnValueMap($validData))
            ->with($validData)
            ->willReturn(true);


        global $pdo;
        $pdo = $this->createMock('PDO');
        $pdo->expects($this->once())
            ->method('prepare')
            ->with("INSERT INTO {$table} id,address VALUES (:ip, :id)")
            ->willReturn($stmt);

        $ipStmt = new ip_request();
        $ipStmt->setTimestampCount($validData,$mysqli);

    }
```

My actual function looks like this:

```
function setTimestampCount($valueData,$mysqli)
    {
 
        $query = $mysqli->prepare ("INSERT INTO `ip` (`id`, `address`)VALUES (:id,:ip)");
        $query ->bindValue(':id', $valueData[0], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query ->bindValue(':ip', $valueData[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        echo $valueData[0];
        $query->execute();

    }
```

The call to this function from the main code comes as:

```
$valueData = [];
array_push($valueData, $id);
array_push($valueData, $ip);
                    
(new ip_request)->setTimestampCount($valueData,$mysqli);
```

The error I have is **Undefined array key 0**, and the errors are pointing at the class function at the

```
$query ->bindValue(':id', $valueData[0], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

and on the test function at the following line:

```
$ipStmt->setTimestampCount($validData,$mysqli);
```

Can anyone help?

thanks

Comment: Just a thought - it may be better to change your main code to do something like your test code instead, you would then have `$query ->bindValue(':id', $valueData['id']` which is clearer (IMHO).

Comment: mysqli, PDO - why do you use both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test case - `$validData` only has id and ip elements - there is no 0 element.

Looks as though it should be

```
$validData = ['99','127.0.0.1'];
```

Comment: Yes that fixed it, what was the point the way I had it before? I found this example from stack, thanks again

Comment: actually error i get now on $query->execute(); line is: "Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" is this the reason that I need the first method?

Comment: Check the table definition, see what foreign keys are defined.  It means that (perhaps) you need a record in another table with that IP address for it to work.

Comment: @spinstaUSA: Please reference the example from stack, thanks again.